# JMeter in distributed mode not all servers taken in consideration in the graphs

Tags: jmeter

I'm doing a performance test with some instances of JMeter and something came up when I was analyzing the JMeter report.

To explain the context, I'm using 3 JMeter servers and each one launches 200 threads, the test runs for 1 minute on non-GUI mode. During the execution, I can clearly see that I have 600 active threads (200 per server).

At the end, my CSV file shows all samples from the 3 servers (I can see this by enabling "hostname" on the jmeter.properties file).

My problem:

On the report I have the Dashboard, that shows the data of my 3 servers (the samples number is the same that the CSV lines, which has all 3 servers).

At the same time, when I see my Active threads over time graph, it only shows 200 (which for me is just 1 server).

JMeter doc says that on the Times vs Threads graph:

> In distributed mode, this graph shows a horizontal axis the number of threads for 1 server. It's a current limitation

And this only for this graph, which means that the other should display the information from all 3 servers...

Am I missing something? Why does the Active threads over time graph shows only 200 threads, even if I saw 600 on my console screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow [Active Threads Over Time Listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) notice you need to change thread group names:

> If you are doing distributed tests, you should name the thread groups like this in your test plan:
>
> ```
> ${__machineName()}_My Threadgroup name
> ```

Comment: As I said, I'm running JMeter on non-gui mode, by command line.
What I don't understand is why it take into consideration the 3 servers to do the statistics table and not to do all the other graphs?

More: why the JMeter manual specifies only that the Times vs Threads graph just uses the data from 1 server, but not all?

Comment: @MZyn but you should save your JMX (usually in GUI mode) with different thread group name

Comment: Even if I have only 1 threadgroup? And even if I dont use the Active Threads Over Time Listener?
I will do a test and I came back to you...

Comment: @MZyn This is also a general solution for distributed tests see http://www.jmeter-archive.org/How-to-reference-thread-group-name-in-JMeter-td3201934.html